# Trouble setting up Mezzanine

Tags: django, apache, mezzanine

My webhost is a2hosting and they provide the following document for getting mezzanine set up:

https://my.a2hosting.com/knowledgebase.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=776

The only part of that guide I didn't do is modifying the public)html root's .htaccess to forward to the folder.  Thus I should be able to access the server via mydomain.com/mezz  (right?)

I've also ran collectstatic.

This is what I get:  http://dapperhat.net/mezz

It looks like the CSS just isnt working and I ran collectstatic but still the same thing.  The weirdest part is that it shows that whether or not I have the server running!

I think it has something to do with the handler in that guide but I dont understand it enough to track it down.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `STATIC_URL` probably points to `/static/` but your site is hosted at `/mezz/`

Try the following setting;

```
STATIC_URL = "/mezz/static/"
```

Comment: Thank you!  After posting that ive been diving into it more and was dancing around that answer....works now :D